# Shopify CLI using Typescript

Tags: typescript, shopify, next.js, koa

I would like to test out building out a shopify app using Typescript by starting with the shopify-app-cli boilerplate, which uses Koa as a server and Nextjs for the front end react javascript.
see `https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-app-cli`

I am having trouble getting the typescript code compiling for both the server and the nextjs frontend code.

Changes:

- All of the file extensions to be either `.tsx` or `.ts`. instead of `.js`
- In package.json, changed "dev" script to use ts-node instead of using `nodemon`

**before**

```
"dev": "NODE_ENV=development nodemon ./server/index.js --watch ./server/index.js",
```

**after**

```
"dev": "NODE_ENV=development ts-node server/server.ts",
```

I can get it to compile the `server.ts` file, however if i change the nextjs files `pages/_app.js` and `pages/index.js` to `.tsx` it can't find them and has this error:

```sh
[ event ] client pings, but there's no entry for page: /
```

This is the `tsconfig.json` file have set up.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"]
}
```

also a gist of `server.ts`, https://gist.github.com/azrielh/73ac202fcce5ce32f19488e4ef5df263.js

Comment: Did you resolve this @Azhop?

Answer (score 5):

I got it to work with basically the setup that you describe.

1. I scaffolded a new app using shopify-cli version 1.5
2. I created the tsconfig.json file you are using
3. I renamed _app.js to _app.tsx, pages/index.js to pages/index.tsx, and server.js to server.tsx
4. I replaced the dev command in package.json as you specified

It all runs, compiles, and sees the TSX pages as expected.

Here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "shopify-app-node",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Shopify's node app for CLI tool",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "oldDev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon ./server/index.js --watch ./server/index.js",
    "dev": "NODE_ENV=development ts-node server/server.ts",
    "build": "NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED=1 next build",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node ./server/index.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-app-node.git"
  },
  "author": "Shopify Inc.",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/shopify/shopify-app-node/issues"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.12.3",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.6.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/register": "^7.6.2",
    "@shopify/app-bridge-react": "^1.15.0",
    "@shopify/app-cli-node-generator-helper": "^1.1.2",
    "@shopify/koa-shopify-auth": "^3.2.0",
    "@shopify/koa-shopify-graphql-proxy": "^4.0.2",
    "@shopify/koa-shopify-webhooks": "^2.5.3",
    "@shopify/polaris": "^5.3.1",
    "@zeit/next-css": "^1.0.1",
    "apollo-boost": "^0.4.4",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.2",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "graphql": "^14.5.8",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^3.0.0",
    "koa": "^2.8.2",
    "koa-router": "^10.0.0",
    "koa-session": "^6.1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "next": "^10.0.0",
    "next-env": "^1.1.0",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
    "react": "^16.10.1",
    "react-apollo": "^3.1.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.10.1",
    "ts-node": "^9.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/preset-stage-3": "^7.0.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.165",
    "@types/node": "^12.19.5",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.56",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.8",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.11.1",
    "babel-jest": "26.6.2",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "enzyme": "3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "1.15.5",
    "eslint": "^7.16.0",
    "husky": "^4.0.7",
    "jest": "26.6.2",
    "lint-staged": "^10.0.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.0",
    "prettier": "^2.1.2",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "15.6.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.14.0",
    "tsmon": "^0.7.3",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,css,json,md}": [
      "prettier --write"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an updated answer for CLI 3.x. This only applies to `web/frontend`.

1. Start by installing the TypeScript package.

```
npm i typescript --save-dev
```

2. Add a `tsconfig.json` with the following.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "esnext",
    "allowJs": false,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "esnext",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "noEmit": true,
    "paths": {
      "*": [
        "node_modules/*"
      ]
    },
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules/**"
  ]
}
```

3. Update `dev` & `build` scripts in the `package.json`. For `dev` we will run our TypeScript compiler in watch mode. For `build`, we can check types once before building.

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "tsc && vite build",
  "dev": "tsc -w ts && vite",
  "test": "vitest",
  "coverage": "vitest run --coverage"
},
```

Shopify uses [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#typescript) under the hood which only performs transpilation on `.ts` files and does NOT perform type checking. This means you'll have to lean on your IDE to point out any compilation errors as the build will still pass.

In-depth steps including adding eslint & prettier can be found [here](https://archiemcquaid.co.uk/blog/add-typescript-eslint-prettier-to-a-shopify-app).

Comment: `npm i typscript --save-dev` should be `npm i typescript --save-dev`